# How can I generate a list of directories, while ignoring .war files?

Tags: bash

I'm looking for a way to generate a list of all directories within a directory, so that I can loop through and take action on each one in the list.

I've been able to get this far:

```
$ for dirs in /var/lib/tomcat7/webapps/*; do echo $dirs; done;
```

This returns the following list:

```
/usr/local/jss/tomcat/webapps/bender
/usr/local/jss/tomcat/webapps/bender.war
/usr/local/jss/tomcat/webapps/fry
/usr/local/jss/tomcat/webapps/fry.war
/usr/local/jss/tomcat/webapps/leela
/usr/local/jss/tomcat/webapps/leela.war
```

This is a good start, but I need to ignore the .war files. How can I do that?

I also need to capture the name of the directory (without the full path) into a variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for dirs in /var/lib/tomcat7/webapps/*/; do ... done
```

With a trailing slash. Or:

```
find /var/lib/tomcat6/webapps -maxdepth 1 -type d
```

---

If you have a the directory name in `$dir`, this will strip out the parent directories:

```
${dir##*/}
```

Example:

```
$ dir=a/b/c
$ echo ${dir##*/}
c
```